# Issues when using a ComboBox inside a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, combobox, scrollviewer

I have a `ListView` that displays a number of elements. Depending on the type of element, the correct `DataTemplate` is picked to display them. One of the templates is for lists of items, which are rendered inside a `ComboBox`.

**DataTemplate**

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="comboBoxTemplate0">
    <ComboBox 
              ItemsSource="{Binding options}" ToolTip="{Binding Title}"
              Margin="2" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
          <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        </Style>
      </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Now, I found an issue that I can't explain, and I believe it may be related to focus somehow, but I don't know. When I open the dropdown for the ComboBox, I can't drag the internal ScrollViewer. I can use the wheel to move up and down, or the arrow keys, but dragging doesn't work, the ScrollViewer in the ListView is activated instead (so dragging the internal ScrollViewer moves the outside one).

I can't seem to reproduce this error, nor can find anyone who has had it happen to them, so I am at a loss. I am thinking about giving up and simply hiding the internal ScrollViewer so it can't be dragged.

**What could be the cause of this behaviour? Why is the external ListView's ScrollViewer moving when I try and drag the internal ComboBox's ScrollViewer?**

**EDIT**

Things tried:

Setting `CanContentScroll` to false - Doesn't work

`PreviewDragOver` isn't fired from the ComboBox

The ListView is listening for 4 events:

PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

```
private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown (object Sender, MouseEventArgs E)
  {
  startPoint_ = E.GetPosition (null);
  }
```

MouseMove

```
private void List_MouseMove (object Sender, MouseEventArgs E)
  {
  if (allowDrag_)
    {
    Vector Difference = startPoint_ - E.GetPosition (null);

    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
        (Math.Abs (Difference.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
         Math.Abs (Difference.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
      {
      PerformDragAndDrop ((DependencyObject)E.OriginalSource, (ListView)Sender);
      }
    }
  }
```

DragEnter

```
private void List_DragEnter (object Sender, DragEventArgs E)
  {
  if (!E.Data.GetDataPresent (Strings.DragnDropFormatString) ||
        Sender == E.Source)
    {
    E.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
  }
```

and Drop

```
private void List_Drop (object Sender, DragEventArgs E)
  {
  if (E.Data.GetDataPresent (Strings.DragnDropFormatString))
    {
    CSettingBase Data = E.Data.GetData (Strings.DragnDropFormatString) as CSettingBase;

    if (LoadedSettings.FirstOrDefault (s => s.Name == Data.Name) == null)
      {
      LoadedSettings.Add (Data);
      Utility.AutoSizeGridViewColumns (ListViewControl);
      this.HideColumns (8);

      if (((ObservableCollection<CSettingBase>)this.ListViewControl.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault (x => x.IsGroup == true) == null)
        {
        this.ExpandColumns (1);
        }
      else
        {
        this.ExpandColumns (8);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

PerformDragAndDrop

```
public void PerformDragAndDrop (DependencyObject Origin, ListView List)
  {
  ListViewItem GridRow = Utility.FindAncestor<ListViewItem> (Origin);

  if (GridRow != null)
    {
    CSettingBase Data = (CSettingBase)List.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer (GridRow);

    // Initialize the Drag and Drop operation
    DataObject DragData = new DataObject (Strings.DragnDropFormatString, Data);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop (GridRow, DragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `ScrollViewer.CanContentScrol`l to `false`?

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan Yeah, doesn't work either.

Comment: Try to see if the PreviewMouseWheel is being fired (it should) for the ComboBox, we talk back later :)

Comment: Sorry, i meant PreviewDragOver

Comment: @Natxo, no that event does not get fired.

Comment: can't replicate your problem? are you subscribing to some events also.. if yes please give them too..

Comment: @KyloRen Events for the ListView? If so, I will add them to the question.

Comment: PerformDragAndDrop  method also... please.

Comment: @KyloRen Added the code for PerformDragAndDrop too

Comment: @MKII still can't replicate your bug. Above details are missing the bugged code..

Comment: @KyloRen I couldn't replicate it either :/ Guess I may have to just break the application apart until I manage to perturb it

Comment: Use WPF Snoop to record events on ComboBox and ListView. It may give you a valuable insight.

Comment: @MKII good to hear if it no longer is replicating. And you should probably delete the question also now.

Comment: @KyloRen Sorry, I meant that I can't make this bug happen in a different project, not that it is no longer happening in the original one.

Comment: @MKII ok... you are still at same place... :( you probably should put a profiler now what code is getting executed when you drag the combobox scroll bar... that's the easiest way to trac the bug

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the issue is that you `List_*event*` is triggering instead of your `ComboBox`s event.

I think this makes sense - unless I'm missing something... :)

Reason being, they are both controls, but one is contained inside another. So, as an example, if your `ListView` was full-screen, then every time you click anything,

```
private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown (object Sender, MouseEventArgs E)
  {
  startPoint_ = E.GetPosition (null);
  }
```

is still being triggered.

Likewise, ***every time*** your mouse cursor moves at all, you're triggering:

```
private void List_MouseMove (object Sender, MouseEventArgs E)
{
  if (allowDrag_)
  {
     Vector Difference = startPoint_ - E.GetPosition (null);

     if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
     (Math.Abs (Difference.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
     Math.Abs (Difference.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
     {
       PerformDragAndDrop ((DependencyObject)E.OriginalSource, (ListView)Sender);
     }
  }
}
```

You can check this by stepping through the code while debugging, or putting breakpoints on these events and see if they are being triggered when you are trying to operate subordinate controls.

Last, if they are, you could simply put a clause in your code to check for what actually has focus and ensure that it's the listview. The problem with this is that it may retain focus even when a child control has been activated. The other way of going about the same action, is to ensure none of the children have focus. This will be more code since you'd be checking every element contained rather than the one containing. However, you could probably just use a method to check this. For example:

```
private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown (object Sender, MouseEventArgs E)
{
  var fs = GetFocusScope(myComboBox);
  IInputElement fe = FocusManager.GerFocusedElement(fs);

  if (fe == myListView)
  {
      startPoint_ = E.GetPosition (null);
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
private bool focusCheck()
{
    bool childFocused;
    var fs = GetFocusScope(myComboBox);
    IInputElement fe = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(fs);

    if (fe == myComboBox) { childFocused = true; }
    if (fe == myButton) { childFocused = true; }
    // then repeat the above for every control contained by your list view.
    return childFocused;
}
private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown (object Sender, MouseEventArgs E)
{
  if (focusCheck() == false) // add this to each event you want to toggle activity of.
  {
      startPoint_ = E.GetPosition (null);
  }
}
```

Anyway, I haven't tested this at all, but it could work. Maybe it at least helps get you thinking in a new direction!

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the root cause. I am still unsure on how to proceed, exactly, but I got a starting point now.

Comment: @MKII I'm not sure what you deduce from above answer. yes it is very clear that when you do any mouseleftbutton down or mouse move event on any inner control, the listview's event will get executed that why I asked for the events in first place. The problem is I'm failed to see any code in above description which will tends to affect the scroll viewer. It left me to believe the fact that there must be any style or behavior for scrollviewer/ scrollbar for which above event are getting executed. and you are not doing anything with controls after drop event.

Comment: @KyloRen Well, I didn't expect the ListView events to keep firing, I thought events had to bubble up, but apparently not. I checked, the wrong events are being fired. So, now I know what's wrong, and I need to find a solution based on that.

Comment: that made me believe the unexpected behavior of scrollviewer happening is must be cause of some other code. If in your events you would had done anything with control hierarchy order there was a change but all you are doing is  ExpandColumns / HideColumns / AutoSizeGridViewColumns etc. from name these method doesn't suggest any such kind of actions.

Comment: @MKII even though the events were executing at listview level, the question was how can they be producing the behave like that. Yes where should the events be is totally a different question. But I'm sure the even the second question's answer rectify your problem it's worth investigating the first one.

Comment: @KyloRen Yeah, I know. This doesn't solve my question (which is why I didn't mark it as my answer), but it gave me an idea. I am still clueless about it, but I will look deeper as soon as I can.

Comment: @MKII  if you can post the code (edited if needed) which shows the layers and how everything is placed you may get better help. There are really only a few possibilities I think...

Comment: @kyle_engineer Sorry, what do you mean by "layers"?